# Meteor Autoform method not called when nested in dynamic template

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm having trouble understanding why AutoForm is not working 100% here. The client-side validation works but submitting the form is not calling the meteor method `insertQuestion`.

As soon as I replace the contents of the `modal` template with the `modalQuestion` template it works and the meteor method is called. So my best guess here is that it has got something to do with `{{> Template.dynamic }}` include but haven't been able to solve this problem myself.

Can anyone tell me why the dynamic template include is not playing nice here?

**layout.html**

```html
<template name="layout">
    {{> modal}}
</template>
```

**layout.js**

```js
Session.set('modalData', {template: "modalQuestion", title: "Test"});
```

**modal.js**

```js
Template.modalBlock.onRendered(function () {
    this.autorun(function() {
        if (Session.get('modalData')) {
            $('#modal').modal();
        }
    });
});
```

**modal.html**

```html
    <!-- A template to include in index.html that dynamically renders the a modal template -->
    <template name="modal">
        {{#if modalData}}
            {{> Template.dynamic template=modalData.template data=modalData}}
        {{/if}}
    </template>

    <!-- A generic block to be used by our modals -->
    <template name="modalBlock">
        <div id="modal">
            <header>{{title}}</header>
            {{> Template.contentBlock }}
        </div>
    </template>

    <!-- A specific modal template -->
    <template name="modalQuestion">
        {{#modalBlock title=title}}
            {{ #autoForm schema=SchemasQuestion meteormethod="insertQuestion" type="method" id="insertQuestionForm" class="form" }}
                {{> afQuickField name="text" label=false placeholder="schemaLabel" }}
                <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
            {{ /autoForm }}
        {{/modalBlock}}
    </template>
```

Comment: Check out yogiben autoform modal package. Either use it or look at how they solved the problems in their code

Comment: I test with yogiben autoform modal and it doesn't work with nested custome method in autoform